# Is there a way to count number of edges and nodes

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I want to calculate number of nodes and edges in a Binary Tree.

Inserting Nodes to the tree

```
class Node<E extends Object>{
    E data;
    Node<E> left;
    Node<E> right;
    protected Node(E data) {
        this.data=data;
        this.left=right=null;
    }
}
public class BinaryTree<E> {
    public  static int numberOfNodes = 0;
    public static int numberOfEdges = 0;
    Node<E> root;
    
    public void insert(E data) {
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(data);
        if(root==null)
            root=newNode;
    }
```

Calculating number of nodes and edges of tree

```
    public void isHarmony() {
        isIt(root);
        System.out.println("Node:"+numberOfNodes+"\tEdge: "+numberOfEdges);
    }
    
    private boolean isIt(Node root) {
        if(root==null) {
            return false;
        }
        if(root.data!=null) {
            numberOfNodes++;        
        }
        if(isIt(root.left)==true)
            numberOfEdges++;
        if(isIt(root.right)==true)
            numberOfEdges++;

        return true;    
    }
```

Testing:

```
        BinaryTree<Integer> bTree = new BinaryTree<>();
        
        Node<Integer> node1 = new Node<Integer>(4);
        Node<Integer> node2 = new Node<Integer>(8);
        Node<Integer> node3 = new Node<Integer>(9);
        Node<Integer> node4 = new Node<Integer>(3);
        Node<Integer> node5 = new Node<Integer>(7);
        Node<Integer> node6 = new Node<Integer>(6);
        
        bTree.root=node1;
        bTree.root.left=node2;
        bTree.root.right=node3;
        bTree.root.right.left=node5;
        bTree.root.right.right=node6;
        bTree.root.left.right= node5;
        bTree.root.left.left=node4;
        
        bTree.isHarmony();
```

The output is:
Node:7  Edge: 6

Actually I want to ask this. I assume my tree was created like this. There are six nodes and six edges. Node with data of 7 is counted twice. How can i fix that.

`

```
        4  
       / \ 
      8   9  
     / \ / \  
    3   7   6
```

`

Comment: *"assume my tree was created like this"*: that is not a tree. In a tree you cannot have two nodes that have more than one path between them. If you really want to work with such non-trees, you need to start by giving your class a different name, as `BinaryTree` is then no longer describing the situation correctly.

Comment: Yes, I know that is not a tree. I just assume there was an error and the node pointing to the same node has been added to the system. I want to detect this state using number of nodes and number of edges.

Comment: Use a HashSet to collect nodes you have already counted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want to find without using any library.

Comment: Then add a boolean member to the Node class that indicates whether you had already visited it. But you'll have to reset all of those before starting.